# In the case of multiple persons, would balance be plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

For example, which of these two sentences is the correct one:

> ... the train started moving, making us all lose our balance.

or

> ... the train started moving, making us all lose our balances

Comment: You could look up Google 3-grams for "lost their balance" and "lost their balances". With this one, the distributive singular is a must. As with 'We all held our breath'.

Answer (score 2):

When the word is reckoned with  as having at most a unique referent for each individual it is usual to keep the word in the singuar. This can be verified for the following words and others.

- [interest](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lost+our+interest+in%2Clost+our+interests+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clost%20our%20interest%20in%3B%2Cc0), [understanding](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gained+our+understanding+of%2Cgained+our+understandings+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgained%20our%20understanding%20of%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cgained%20our%20understanding%20of%3B%2Cc0), [hatred](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=our+hatred+for%2Clost+our+hatreds+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cour%20hatred%20for%3B%2Cc0), [love](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=our+love+for%2Cour+loves+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cour%20love%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cour%20loves%20for%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cour%20love%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cour%20loves%20for%3B%2Cc0)

However, when the word can be reckoned with as having more than one referent for each individual, then the plural tends to be more frequent, this, along the line of a gradient according to the greater plausibility of more than one referent. In the case where  several referents are involved for each person the plural must be used. It is not clear whether the plural might not be used also sometimes when there is a unique referent.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Interest??  Not always.

Comment: Words are not "conceived as having a unique referent for each individual". That is just meaningless in English. A person can have a concern or concerns (two different meanings).  Only context will tell. Some nouns like balance referring to how you are positioned physically on your feet are not used in the plural. "All of us lost our balance doing that dance". referents in semiology refer to actual things in reality, not mental pictures.

Comment: @Lambie Meaningless? No, archaic, yes. It means "grasp mentally". I'll change that.

Comment: @Lambie It is implied nowhere that mental pictures are at stakes. Anyway, to several actual things corresponds in the mind the mental representation of that plurality. You miss the point. I am talking about the actual things. The concept of several balances for only one human being does not exist, whereas the concept of several resolutions relative to a single person is a realistic concept.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, a group of persons with each several particular interests, and all of them losing all of their interests is a possible situation; then it would be normal to say "We all lost our interests.". However, in that case the word is not reckoned with as denoting a single referent for each person.

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent question that raises an issue that seems backward.  When deciding numerical agreement, you always match singular with singular, and plural with plural.  Here, "us all" refers to a GROUP, so it SEEMS plural.  But it is not. It is ONE group, not many.  So the referent must be singular: "I lose my balance. The group loses its balance." If it were truly plural, it would be referring to separate items:  The balances of bass, treble, and midrange required adjustment.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please get used to using `**double asterisks for bold**` instead of capitals. When you **mention** a word, set that in `*italics*` with a single asterisk.